Doubts about alternative definition to connection in differential geometry
We consider a variety M and coordinate bases of the tangent space ${∂_i}^N_{i=1}$, and of the tangent space ${dx^i}^N_{i=1}$. We consider the following definition of connection ∇ on the variety, as an application that to a vector field X and to a 1-form differential η associates another 1-form differential, given by ∇Xη:$$(X,η)→∇_Xη∈X^*(M),$$ which is convenient for defining the covariant derivative of differential ∇η forms.
We define the covariant derivative of a 1-differential form acting on two vector fields X and Y as:$$∇η(X,Y) =∇_Xη(Y).$$
a) We define the components of the connection $Γ^j_{ki}$ from the coordinate bases ${∂_i}^N_{i=1}$ and ${dx^i}^N_{i=1}$, as $$∇_{∂i}dx^j=-Γ^j_{ik}dx^k.$$ Using this expression , find the components of ∇η in a coordinate basis.
b) For the case Y=$\partial_l$ in the above expressions, and considering a generic vector field $X=X^i∂_i$ and a generic differential 1-form $η=η_jdx^j$, find the value of a ∈R for which $$X^i∂_iη_l=∇_Xη(∂_l)  +aη(∇_X∂_l)$$ is satisfied.
c) Calculate the components of $d∇_Xdx^j$
My solution for the problem is the following:
a)$$ ∇_i\eta_j = ∇_{\partial_i}\eta (\partial_j)= ∇_{\partial_i}\eta_rdx^r (\partial_j)=((\partial_i \eta_r)dx^r+\eta_r(∇_{\partial_i}dx^r))(\partial_j) = (\partial_i\eta_j)-\eta_rΓ^r_{ij},$$
where I used that $dx^k\partial_j=\delta^k_j$ and the above definitions.
b) The first term of RHS:
$$∇_X\eta(\partial_l)=X^i∇_{\partial_i}\eta(\partial_l)=x^i((\partial_i\eta_l)-\eta_rΓ^r_{il}).$$
So the second term of RHS must be equal to: $\eta_rΓ^r_{il}$ but I am not sure how to define $∇_X∂_l$ as is not defined above
c) $$d(∇_Xdx^j) = d(-x^iΓ^j_{ik}dx^k)=\partial_p(-x^iΓ^j_{ik})dx^p\wedge dx^k$$
Which is a 2-form. And by the way in this last statement if the connection is torsion free, the last equation would be 0 because $Γ^j_{ik}$ will be symmetric and wedge product antisymmetric, woldn't be?
Can you help with b) statement and check if I have made any mistakes in the other sections. Thanks!

To clarify, when you write $\nabla_X\eta(Y)$, this means $(\nabla_X\eta)(Y)$. You should understand that $\Gamma^j_{ik}$ is defined by $\nabla_{\partial_k} \partial_i = \Gamma^j_{ik}\partial_j$ and then $\nabla_X(\eta(Y)) = (\nabla_X\eta)(Y) + \eta(\nabla_X Y)$ defines $(\nabla_X\eta)(Y)$. Work it out.

I understand recently that all I've done in a) was showing that the covariant derivative acting on 1-form is just the same as in a vector but with a minus in the connection components. So $\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_l=Γ^j_{il}\partial_j$ is just the usual definition of the covariant derivative acting on a vector.
In c) in my answer: $\partial_p(-x^iΓ^j_{ik})dx^p\wedge dx^k$ the i,j index is free but it is a 2-form because Γ is not a tensor, isn't it?
